# Javascript - Find source of console.errors in webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, console.log

I'm developing a React app and incorporated a few packages, some of which seem to be spitting out uncaught `console.error` messages despite UI and functionality working just fine. The Console output currently looks like this:

[image]

I can't seem to find anything online about this, but is there any way I can track down and silence these messages? In particular I'm looking at the one saying `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`, since the others seem to be coming from the React debugger.

EDIT: The error seems to be a side effect of some sort of Adblocker/tracker blocker built into Brave. Is there anyway I can still catch that in my Javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it could be something like a cache or some extension. Since you've said that you searched for a solution online and didn't find anything, I believe you already tried these solutions, but if not, here is something you can try:

- Start Chrome with your extensions disabled or start in incoginito mode (the extensions will be disabled by default).
- Clean your browser cache and cookies.
- If you are like me (I hope not) and open 99+ tabs in your broswer, close them, it could be a problem due lack of memory.
- Check the network tab to see if Chrome failed to download any resource file.

These are the tips I can give to you, I hope it helps.

Comment: Your advice made me try it on Firefox Incognito (rather than Brave) - where I didn't have plugins/shields/etc - and you were right, the error didn't occur. Still wish I could silence it though!